# How to change JFileChooser label "Look in:" to "Save in:" (not title)?

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jfilechooser

How to change **JFileChooser** label "Look in:" to "Save in:" (not title)? Here you can see what I want to change:

[image]

Comment: Extend file chooser and then modify fields? :p

Comment: Hmm.. `installUI(JComponent c)` method is used, it means I must look somewhere in `JFileChooser` current UI implementation. Maybe someone has already have done it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I found the solution, maybe for someone it will be useful too:

```
JFileChooser chooser = new JFileChooser("Open");

//Set the text and language of all the components in JFileChooser
UIManager.put("FileChooser.openDialogTitleText", "Open");
UIManager.put("FileChooser.lookInLabelText", "LookIn");
UIManager.put("FileChooser.openButtonText", "Open");
UIManager.put("FileChooser.cancelButtonText", "Cancel");
UIManager.put("FileChooser.fileNameLabelText", "FileName");
UIManager.put("FileChooser.filesOfTypeLabelText", "TypeFiles");
UIManager.put("FileChooser.openButtonToolTipText", "OpenSelectedFile");
UIManager.put("FileChooser.cancelButtonToolTipText","Cancel");
UIManager.put("FileChooser.fileNameHeaderText","FileName");
UIManager.put("FileChooser.upFolderToolTipText", "UpOneLevel");
UIManager.put("FileChooser.homeFolderToolTipText","Desktop");
UIManager.put("FileChooser.newFolderToolTipText","CreateNewFolder");
UIManager.put("FileChooser.listViewButtonToolTipText","List");
UIManager.put("FileChooser.newFolderButtonText","CreateNewFolder");
UIManager.put("FileChooser.renameFileButtonText", "RenameFile");
UIManager.put("FileChooser.deleteFileButtonText", "DeleteFile");
UIManager.put("FileChooser.filterLabelText", "TypeFiles");
UIManager.put("FileChooser.detailsViewButtonToolTipText", "Details");
UIManager.put("FileChooser.fileSizeHeaderText","Size");
UIManager.put("FileChooser.fileDateHeaderText", "DateModified");

//Set icons for the JFileChooser
UIManager.put("FileView.directoryIcon", new ImageIcon(FileSystem.class.getResource("folder.png")));
UIManager.put("FileChooser.homeFolderIcon", new ImageIcon(FileSystem.class.getResource("user-home.png")));
UIManager.put("FileView.computerIcon", new ImageIcon(FileSystem.class.getResource("computer.png")));
UIManager.put("FIleView.floppyDriveIcon", new ImageIcon(FileSystem.class.getResource("media-floppy.png")));
UIManager.put("FileView.hardDriveIcon", new ImageIcon(FileSystem.class.getResource("drive-harddisk.png")));
UIManager.put("FileView.fileIcon", new ImageIcon(FileSystem.class.getResource("file.png")));
UIManager.put("FileChooser.upFolderIcon", new ImageIcon(FileSystem.class.getResource("go.png")));
UIManager.put("FileChooser.newFolderIcon", new ImageIcon(FileSystem.class.getResource("folder-new.png")));
UIManager.put("FileView.fileIcon", new ImageIcon(FileSystem.class.getResource("file.png")));
UIManager.put("FileChooser.listViewIcon", new ImageIcon(FileSystem.class.getResource("listIcon.png")));
UIManager.put("FileChooser.detailsViewIcon", new ImageIcon(FileSystem.class.getResource("details.png")));

//Update UI
SwingUtilities.updateComponentTreeUI(chooser);
```

Answer (score 2):

2021 Answer:

The other answers either didn't work or were too problematic to implement. The most simplest way to achieve this for me was to use `chooser.showOpenDialog(yourJFrame)` and `chooser.showSaveDialog(yourJFrame)`.

For example:

```
JFrame frame = new JFrame();
JFileChooser chooser = new JFileChooser(); 
chooser.showOpenDialog(frame);
```

Result using `.showOpenDialog()`:

[image]

Result using `.showSaveDialog()`:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

```
JFileChooser chooser = new JFileChooser(); 
chooser.setDialogType(0);  // gives 'Look In'
chooser.setDialogType(1);  // gives 'Save In'
```